# Can I print both array index and value in the same line?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n' ARR=(`lvs | grep -v LV | awk '{print $1}'`)

for A in ${ARR[*]}
do
        echo $A
done

for ((i=0;i<${#ARR[*]};i++))
do
        echo $i
done
```

**The result of the above script**

home

root

swap

fedora

0

1

2

3

**I want the following results**

0 home

1 root

2 swap

3 fedora

Comment: Replace `echo` with `printf "%s"`.

Comment: sorry, 
It is not the answer I want.

Comment: `for idx in "${!ARR[@]}"; do item=${ARR[$idx]}; echo "$idx $item" done`

Comment: BTW, arrays aren't guaranteed to work with `#!/bin/sh`; on many systems, `/bin/sh` is provided by dash, which doesn't support them. Always use `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use bash-only features.

Comment: thx !!!!!!!!!!
It's the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you concatenate each $A with a separator, and then echo the string at the end if you want it on one line.

Comment: sorry, 
It is not the answer I want.